# Timeout context not inside a Task [Python 3.x]

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am not really familiar with async functions but I have worked in creating discord bots in the past and know some basics here and there to make it work. I am currently building a React based front end for my discord bot so am using flask and flask async as an API.

Here is my a Fork of the discord.py Bot.

```py
class BotFork(commands.Bot):
    """
    An extended version of the discord.ext.commands.Bot class. This class 
    supports additional functionality like managing cogs and controlling 
    the bot's online status.

    Attributes:
        setup (bool): Indicates if the bot has been set up.
        active_game (Any): Stores the current active game instance.
        token (str): Discord bot token.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initializes the BotFork instance.

        Args:
            *args: Variable length argument list.
            **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.
        """
        self.setup = False
        self.active_game = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, guild_ids=[])
        super().add_cog(HelperCog(self))
        super().add_cog(GameCog(self))

    def set_token(self, token):
        """
        Sets the bot token.

        Args:
            token (str): Discord bot token.
        """
        self.token = token

    async def on_ready(self):
        """
        Asynchronous event handler for when the bot is ready.
        """
        for guild in self.guilds:
            print(f'{self.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
                  f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')

    async def run(self):
        """
        Starts the bot. If the bot is already set up, changes the bot's presence to online.
        """
        if not self.setup:
            self.setup = True
            threading.Thread(target=super().run, args=(self.token,)).start()
        else:
           await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)

    async def stop(self):
        """
        Asynchronous method to stop the bot, changing its presence to offline.
        """
        await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)


    async def execute(self, cog_name, method_name, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Executes a method from a cog.

        Args:
            cog_name (str): Name of the cog.
            method_name (str): Name of the method.
            *args: Variable length argument list.
            **kwargs: Arbitrary keyword arguments.

        Returns:
            Any: The return value of the method.
        """
        cog = self.get_cog(cog_name)
        method = getattr(cog, method_name)
        if cog is None or method is None:
            raise Exception("Cog or method not found.")
        
        if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(method):
            return await method(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a function called `setup_game()`  that creates certain channels, categories and messages. I initially had it in `GameCog` which was called using the `execute()` function in the  BotFork class. I tried copying the function in the bot class and its functionality in the API endpoint itself but it keeps on throwing the same error. Here is the API endpoint and the function.

```py
@app.route('/api/createchannels', methods=['POST'])
async def create_channels():
    await bot.setup_game()
    return jsonify({'message': 'Channels created successfully'}), 200
```

```py
 async def setup_game(self):
        """
        Sets up a game instance.

        Args:
            game (dict): The game data.
        """
        game = self.active_game
        guild = self.guilds[0]
        category = await guild.create_category("Jeopardy")
        game_category = category
        voice_channels = [] 
        for team in game.teams:
            role = await guild.create_role(name=team.get_name())
            self.roles.append(role)

            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, connect=False, speak=False),
                role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, connect=True, speak=True)
            }

            channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(team.get_name(), category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
            voice_channels.append(channel)

        announcement_channel = await guild.create_text_channel("announcements", category=category)
        scoreboard_channel = await guild.create_text_channel("scoreboard", category=category)
```

This is the RunTime error that occurs with this function

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2023 03:29:28] "POST /api/createchannels HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/routes/api.py", line 247, in create_channels
    await bot.setup_game()
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/utils/bot.py", line 127, in setup_game
    category = await guild.create_category("Jeopardy")
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1586, in create_category
    data = await self._create_channel(
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 283, in request
    async with self.__session.request(
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1167, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 493, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/mnt/d/discord_bot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 705, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```